# running android source from git tree

Tags: android, android-source

I just downloaded the most recent camera app on the cupcake branch of the android source tree, mostly in order to find examples to steal from in order to control the camera in my own application. It got the source from [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/cupcake). However, when I opened up the extracted folder as a new android project in eclipse, I am getting TONS of compile errors, examples below. I have the Android 1.5 library in the build path. It only has android.jar in it? It is only supposed to have android.jar in it-right? Is there something else that I should be doing? Why can't I compile something straight off of the tree?

Error examples:

mScrollX cannot be resolved

MediaStore.EXTRA_SHOW_ACTION_ICONS cannot be resolved

The method commitUpdates() is undefined for the type Cursor

etc.

Also: an error in the Manifest File: Class com.android.camera.UploadService does not exist

Comment: android.jar is correct, but what kind of error messages do you get? Can you edit your question and let us see the most important ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can't build it from the SDK 'cause it is too old, and at the time of the release, google was still depending on in-house stuff that they never shipped out. Later versions are buildable with the SDK (I got the version for Froyo working) but not poor little cupcake.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f37cc0e732e0101e?pli=1